# Validation of current file using XML schema

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xml-namespaces

This is what I get when I try to Validate against schema B.xsd:

> Validation of current file using XML schema: ERROR: Element
>   '{http://NamespaceTest.com/OrderTypes/}University': No matching global
>   declaration available for the validation root.

XML:

```
<p:University xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://NamespaceTest.com/B B.xsd" 
                xmlns:p="http://NamespaceTest.com/B/"
                xmlns:cmn="http://NamespaceTest.com/A/">
<cmd:College>
    <cmd:Dept>
        <cmd:Course>
        <cmd:Teacher>a</cmd:Teacher>
        <cmd:Student>b</cmd:Student> 
        </cmd:Course>
    </cmd:Dept>
</cmd:College> 
</p:University>
```

B.XSD(University):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:c="http://NamespaceTest.com/A" elementFormDefault="qualified"      targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/B" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import schemaLocation="A.xsd" namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/A" />
      <xs:complexType name="University">
       <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Col" type="c:College" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

A.XSD(College):

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/A" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:complexType name="College">
  <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Dept">
    <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Course">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Teacher" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="Student" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to try something like this(just as an exercise): University(B) uses College(A)and its subelements. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach:

**Firstly**, although you have defined the *University* type in your schema, that type is not inherently available for use in instance documents simply by referencing the schema namespace. The easiest thing to do in this instance* is add a root element to your schema of type *University*:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:c="http://NamespaceTest.com/A" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/B"
           xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/B" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="A.xsd" namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/A" />
  <xs:complexType name="University">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Col" type="c:College" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- Root element -->
  <xs:element type="University" name="University" />
</xs:schema>
```

Note: if you're adding a root element you'll also need to add the root namespace declaration:

```
xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/B"
```

*If you read the comments below this answer, Petru has outlined a way of referencing types from a schema which does not have a root element defined.

**Secondly**, the type *College*, though defined in A.xsd, logically "belongs" to B.xsd (because B.xsd already imports A.xsd), so your xml instance does not need explicit knowledge of the types in A.xsd.

So you only need to reference a single target namespace, `http://NamespaceTest.com/B` to have access to all the types:

```
<ns0:University xmlns:ns0="http://NamespaceTest.com/B">
  <ns0:Col>
    <Dept>
      <Course>
        <Teacher>a</Teacher>
        <Student>b</Student>
      </Course>
    </Dept>
  </ns0:Col>
</ns0:University>
```

Comment: What you said with `your schema is not valid as no root element is defined. Every logical xsd schema requires a root element` is incorrect. I could write <dummy xsi:type="c:University" xmlns:c="..." ... > and it will work on any compliant processor. It would simply be valid, as per the intent of XML Schema Instance...

Comment: Of course you're correct @petrugardea. What i meant was you cannot create an xml instance of a schema unless it has a root element.

Comment: Somehow, I don't think you understood my comment. You said `your schema is not valid as no root element is defined`; to `correct` it, you've created `<xs:element type="University" name="University" />` My point is, you don't need this last element to validate an instance XML.

Comment: @PetruGardea I dont' understand. Forgive my ignorance, but how are you supposed to create an an instance document which complies to  a schema which only defines complex types?

Comment: Please try what I've already shown above `<dummy xsi:type="c:University" xmlns:c="..." ... >` match the prefixes, etc. Validate using .NET, or Java and see what you get. If you think it's weird, read the spec, think how xsi:type works, or how the WSDL spec deals with parts that use `type` instead of `element` to define a message part, etc.

Comment: @Petru OK I get your point. I was not aware of xsi:type. I have updated my answer to reflect. However, it's pretty clear from the OP's question that they expected to be able to reference the University type solely by specifying the namespace. In that instance, the simplest and most convenient thing to do to solve the OP's question would be to define a root element.